# Better TIF to PNG conversion with Bitmap.Save()?

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, tiff

**Update:** Tried `SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;` and it's noticeable at full zoom, but it doesn't solve the problem, the problem is just anti-aliased now...

The TIFs are scanned documents, and contain things like lines for tables and text.

Current approach:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;    

var image = Image.FromFile(tifFileName);

Image bitmap = new Bitmap(image, (int)(image.Width), (int)(image.Height));

var imageFinal = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(imageFinal);

graphic.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);

using(var imgStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageFinal.Save(imgStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    return new MemoryStream(imgStream.GetBuffer());
}
```

But, it ends up looking like garbage, for example any kind of slightly slanted line has a hint of a stair step, and other fine elements such as text look rough. Especially in comparison to using GIMP to save a TIF as a PNG, which looks great.

So, is there something I can add to make this work better? Or am I going to have to find another approach entirely?

Comment: i am not familiar with this libary, but there should be an antyalias flag somewhere. It will load and save your pictures without the stair stepped lines

Comment: Ah I should have included that, it's System.Drawing, though that doesn't mean you're any more familiar with it, just thought I'd at least name it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My immediate impression is that you're going to too much trouble, since you aren't resizing:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Sample.tiff");
image.Save(@"C:\Sample.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

If using the Image type doesn't solve your aliasing problems, try picking your encoder manually:

```
#region Using Directives

using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

#endregion

namespace TiffToBitmap
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // Just save the image.
            SaveImage(@"C:\Sample1.png", "image/tiff");

            // Get a byte array from the converted image.
            var imageBytes = GetBytes("image/tiff");

            // Save it for easy comparison.
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Sample2.png", imageBytes);
        }

        private static byte[] GetBytes(string mimeType)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Sample.tiff");

            var encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            var imageCodecInfo = encoders.FirstOrDefault(encoder => encoder.MimeType == mimeType);

            if (imageCodecInfo == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var imageEncoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                imageEncoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
                image.Save(memoryStream, imageCodecInfo, imageEncoderParams);

                return memoryStream.GetBuffer();
            }
        }

        private static void SaveImage(string path, string mimeType)
        {
            var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Sample.tiff");

            var encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            var imageCodecInfo = encoders.FirstOrDefault(encoder => encoder.MimeType == mimeType);

            if (imageCodecInfo == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var imageEncoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            imageEncoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            image.Save(path, imageCodecInfo, imageEncoderParams);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, I actually left out an if statement that does do resizing because my current issue is happening without it, however that doesn't mean that what you've given me won't do the trick, trying it now

Comment: If that doesn't do the trick post me a sample TIFF and I'll knock it out.  We have a guy that's sharp with this stuff if I need help.

Comment: FYI, in the office, we often use this SDK for imaging tasks.  It's API can be a little confusing at first, but it works really, really well: http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/ImageDraw-SDK-NET/ImageDraw_SDK_NET.aspx?tabid=95&prodid=8

Comment: Ok thanks, I'd have to scrub one since they contain PII. One side question: To your knowledge is there any part of any of the code in the question or answer that is not thread safe? This is going to be used in a web app and one of my coworkers expressed some concern from something he may have read in the past.

Comment: The code above is ABSOLUTELY NOT thread-safe.  You'd want to remove the static modifiers and encapsulate the image processing in an instance per thread.

Comment: Answer updated to just go ahead and include both direct to file and a version that returns a byte[].  You can just grab the whole thing, throw it in a new console app, run it, and start tooling around.

Comment: Ali (image guy here in the office) says to use PngBitmapEncoder.  It is a newer type and intended to deal directly with PNG.  He also says there is  TiffBitmapDecoder type as well for control over reading that TIFF.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx

Comment: I'm re-reading your sentence a few comments up, what do you mean "in an instance per thread"?

Comment: As a quick sample, I put all this code in a static type and used static methods to do the work.  In a production quality application, you would just remove all the static references and put the worker methods in their own utility class of some kind.  Each thread that needs to simultaneously be resizing images should create its own instance of that utility class.

Comment: @ioSamurai - An instance per thread means that you would put all this logic in class of some kind.  Maybe something like public class TiffToPngConverter(string path, string mimeType).  The you would create a new instance of that class in each thread, or pass an instance into the thread before calling start.  Using statics for this kind of thing means that if two threads enter the method simultaneously they will be accessing and modifying the same shared resources, which is very bad.  And you're welcome for the help.  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my realization of image/tiff type conversion:

Convertion block:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert Tiff image to another mime-type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tiffImage">Source Tiff file</param>
/// <param name="mimeType">Desired result mime-type</param>
/// <returns>Converted image</returns>
public Bitmap ConvertTiffToBitmap(Image tiffImage, string mimeType)
{
    var imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(encoder => encoder.MimeType == MimeType.Tiff);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Setting encode params
        var imageEncoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1)
        {
            Param = {[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L)}
        };

        tiffImage.Save(memoryStream, imageCodecInfo, imageEncoderParams);

        var converter = new ImageConverter();

        // Reading stream data to new image
        var tempTiffImage = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(memoryStream.GetBuffer());

        // Setting new result mime-type
        imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(encoder => encoder.MimeType == mimeType);
        tempTiffImage?.Save(memoryStream, imageCodecInfo, imageEncoderParams);

        return new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(memoryStream, true));
    }
}

public static class MimeType
{
    public const string Bmp = "image/bmp";
    public const string Gif = "image/gif";
    public const string Jpeg = "image/jpeg";
    public const string Png = "image/png";
    public const string Tiff = "image/tiff";
}
```

Usage:

```
var sourceImg = Image.FromFile(@"C:\MyImage.tif", true);

var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().First(c => c.FormatID == sourceImg.RawFormat.Guid);
if (codec.MimeType == MimeType.Tiff)
{
    sourceImg = ConvertTiffToBitmap(sourceImg, MimeType.Jpeg);
}
```

Hope, it could be usefull